# Running Drools rules on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, drools

A client of mine has asked me to look into moving an app that's using Drools from AWS to Google App Engine. I've done a bit of research, and from some old postings on the net, there seemed to be some problems using Drools on GAE, due to the fact that it does file I/O which is not allowed.

Does anyone know if this has been addressed in a newer version of Drools? I've tried searching, but the only responses I get are fairly old (> 1 year)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know it will not work out-of-the-box with newest version, did you try it at least? If you have errors we can help you to solve them if we see at least a possibility to make it work.
Cheers

Comment: Based on what I read, I haven't tried it yet. My client just wanted a quick look to see if it was possible, without going to any great effort. My reading leads me to think it might be possible, but it'll take a bit of work wrt the drools part. I was hoping that the newer versions had solved the problem and someone here could say for sure that it works out of the box.

Comment: You will need to try it and see what happens, it should work in some way, the big problem in my perspective is the reduced JVM that the google engine provides. As I told you, we can help if you find errors. Cheers